# Inserting elements at desired positions in a STL map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

```
map <int, string> rollCallRegister;
map <int, string> :: iterator rollCallRegisterIter;
map <int, string> :: iterator temporaryRollCallRegisterIter;

rollCallRegisterIter     = rollCallRegister.begin ();
tempRollCallRegisterIter = rollCallRegister.insert (rollCallRegisterIter, pair <int, string> (55, "swati"));

rollCallRegisterIter++;
tempRollCallRegisterIter = rollCallRegister.insert (rollCallRegisterIter, pair <int, string> (44, "shweta"));

rollCallRegisterIter++;
tempRollCallRegisterIter = rollCallRegister.insert (rollCallRegisterIter, pair <int, string> (33, "sindhu"));

// Displaying contents of this map.
cout << "\n\nrollCallRegister contains:\n";
for (rollCallRegisterIter = rollCallRegister.begin(); rollCallRegisterIter != rollCallRegister.end(); ++rollCallRegisterIter)
{
    cout << (*rollCallRegisterIter).first << " => " << (*rollCallRegisterIter).second << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
rollCallRegister contains:
33 => sindhu
44 => shweta
55 => swati
```

I have incremented the iterator. Why is it still getting sorted? And if the position is supposed to be changed by the map on its own, then what's the purpose of providing an iterator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) is a sorted associative container.

> In a map, the key value is generally used to uniquely identify the element, while the mapped value is some sort of value associated to this key.

According to [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/) position parameter is

> the position of the first element to be compared for the insertion
>   operation. Notice that this does not force the new element to be in
>   that position within the map container (elements in a set always
>   follow a specific ordering), but this is actually an indication of a
>   possible insertion position in the container that, if set to the
>   element that precedes the actual location where the element is
>   inserted, makes for a very efficient insertion operation. iterator is
>   a member type, defined as a bidirectional iterator type.

So the purpose of this parameter is mainly slightly increasing the insertion speed by narrowing the range of elements.

You can use `std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>>` if the order of insertion is important.

Comment: But then what is the purpose of specifying position with an iterator?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Position refers to the first element to be compared for the insertion operation. Notice that this does not force the new element to be in that position within the map container. Here is a [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/)

Comment: `Position refers to the first element to be compared for the insertion operation` For what is comparison needed? I am following that link only, is the reason mentioned there somewhere? I couldn't see it.

Comment: Comparison is needed for sorting the keys in the order which you specify with a comparison class. Please go to the link in the answer and read about `std::map`.

Comment: That link says: `Position of the first element to be compared for the insertion operation.
Notice that this does not force the new element to be in that position within the map container (elements in a set always follow a specific ordering), but this is actually an indication of a possible insertion position in the container that, if set to the element that precedes the actual location where the element is inserted, makes for a very efficient insertion operation.` Does this mean that iterator is used "only" for "speed" and has nothing to do with position?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Yes. Because the position of elements are determined by the comparison class, that is `std::less<int>` for your case.

Comment: @Anisha - Yes, it is a (possible) optimization. If you tell the map the correct position for the insertion, the operation might be done slightly faster.

Comment: @sad_man If you can add this little detail in your answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Yes the asnwer was not complete. Sorry. It is OK now, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The interface is indeed slightly confusing, because it looks very much like `std::vector<int>::insert` (for example) and yet does not produce the same effect...

For associative containers, such as `set`, `map` and the new `unordered_set` and co, you completely relinquish the control over the order of the elements (as seen by iterating over the container). In exchange for this loss of control, you gain efficient look-up.

It would not make sense to suddenly give you control over the insertion, as it would let you break invariants of the container, and you would lose the efficient look-up that is the reason to use such containers in the first place.

And thus `insert(It position, value_type&& value)` does not insert at said position...

However this gives us some room for optimization: when inserting an element in an associative container, a look-up need to be performed to locate where to insert this element. By letting you specify a *hint*, you are given an opportunity to *help* the container speed up the process.

This can be illustrated for a simple example: suppose that you receive elements already sorted by way of some interface, it would be wasteful not to use this information!

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename InputStream>
void insert(std::map<Key, Value>& m, InputStream& s) {
  typename std::map<Key, Value>::iterator it = m.begin();

  for (; s; ++s) {
    it = m.insert(it, *s).first;
  }
}
```

Some of the items might not be well sorted, but it does not matter, if two consecutive items are in the right order, then we will gain, otherwise... we'll just perform as usual.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, You answer is helpful indeed, but too late. +1

Answer (score 1):

The map is always sorted, but you give a "hint" as to where the element may go as an optimisation.

The insertion is O(log N) but if you are able to successfully tell the container where it goes, it is constant time.

Thus if you are creating a large container of already-sorted values, then each value will get inserted at the end, although the tree will need rebalancing quite a few times.

Comment: Do you mean, that "we" need to tell the compiler how to sort? This is impractical if the list is big, isn't it?

Comment: @AnishaKaul We don't tell the _compiler_ anything, but the _container_; `std::map` allows you to specify the correct position in the map, so it doesn't have to go looking for it. If the position you specify is incorrect, it will still search for the correct one. You can do this when you expect the contents to be (roughly) sorted, which can have an important impact on large collections.

Answer (score 0):

As sad_man says, it's associative. If you set a value with an existing key, then you overwrite the previous value.

Now the iterators are necessary because you don't know what the keys are, usually.

Comment: What is the other way that it can be written with iterator, and without specifying the key?

Comment: Ah! I see your point now. You meant the iterator used in the insert() calls. I would use the [] operator instead. rollCallRegister[33] = "sindhu";

Comment: You may want to check these pages out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/

Comment: Alexis see my comments on the other answer. I was in a misconception.

Comment: And also, in ` rollCallRegister[33] = "sindhu";` the key is already known.\